# In a Euclidean domain's division with remainders, is $r=0$ if $t$ divides $s$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-domain

A Euclidean domain $D$ has a function $F$ from nonzero elements of $D$ to nonnegative integers that makes division with remainder possible in $D$: Let $D$ have elements $t$ and $s$, and $t$ is nonzero. Then $D$ has elements $q$ and $r$ for which $s = tq + r$, and if the remainder $r$ is nonzero too, then $F(t) > F(r)$. If $r$ happens to be zero, then $t$ divides $s$ because $s=tq$. If $t$ happens to divides $s$, then is $r$ zero? If $t$ divides $s$, then $s = ut$ for an element $u$ in $D$. Then $r=t(u-q)$ is an element of the ideal generated by $t$, so the ideal generated by $r$ is contained in the ideal $(t)$.

Do any of these mean $r=0$?

We have $t$ divides $r$, which is unusual for nonzero remainders, but, unlike with the Euclidean domain of the integers $\mathbb Z$, I don't see the precise contradiction for a general Euclidean domain $D$. Bernard poses a good question. Usually, the $F$ that allows us to deduce $r=0$.

Something that might help: Can we deduce the existence of a function $G$ that satisfies $G(p) \le G(pv)$ and $G(p)=0$ if and only if $p=0$?

Thanks, and have a happy new year!

Comment: Do you suppose that you will stop editing your question eventually?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It wasn't working. I stopped editing already.

Comment: What is $F$ in this context?

Comment: @Bernard any function from nonzero elements of D to nonnegative integers for which the division with remainder is possible. What's the difference if I use the other definition of F, for which $F(a) \le F(ab)$?

Comment: *Any* function, really?

Comment: @Bernard I edited my comment. Now I also edited my question.

Comment: Since $r=t(u-q)$ and $D$ is a domain, either $u-q=0$ or $t=0$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: @rogerl If $u-q=0$ or $t=0$, then $r=0$, but how did you obtain 'either $u-q=0$ or $t=0$'? If $r=0$, then $u-q=0$ or $t=0$ because $D$ is a domain, but $r=0$ is precisely what I am trying to prove.

Comment: @rogerl Actually, I was thinking to say something like $ar=0$. Since a is nonzero and $D$ is a domain, $r=0$. If not $ar=0$, then maybe $br=0$ or $qr=0$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you think of an $F$ that is a counterexample?